# How should I materialize DDD entities with private setters from the persistence layer?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm just starting to figure out DDD. Anemic domain models (that I learn were actually no more than persistence models) and pushing logic into the view models just wasn't cutting it. So I've modeled one of the more complex contexts (a feed nutrition/price optimizer). I'm totally on board with the fact that the DDD entities have private setters and expose readonly collections, and that the only way to mutate them is to call methods on the entities. Very easy to test, hard to misuse.

Here's my problem. It's straightforward to save this thing to the database. What's not obvious to me is how to materialize it again without breaking encapsulation.

I've been using Entity Framework to load data models. I know it is capable of using the domain entities' private setters, but: 1) the magic of reflection can be misleading to reason about. 2) I definitely don't want to try to skip the data models and coerce the domain models to try to play well with EF. 3) The database is slightly less normalized than the domain model. 4) I don't think EF plays well with `IReadOnlyList<>`.

I also tried reconstructing and replaying the method calls which would cause the entity to be in an equivalent state, but that seems like unnecessary complexity. It isn't obvious to me whether the code is correct. Also this method would trigger quite a lot of linear programming solving and lag.

In order to keep the domain entities clean, the last resort I can think of is an internal static factory method on each entity called `Materialize` which receives the fields as parameters and returns a new instance of the entity. The respository should be the only thing accessing it. Is this a good solution? What else should I consider?

Edit: rather than materializing saved state, I'm having my repositories simulate event sourcing (the replay approach). I like this direction. The database is not event sourcing yet but could easily switch at any point, since the repositories are hiding that.

Comment: The first 3 points are really more feelings than precisely defined obstacles. 4) is admittedly better in NHibernate than it is in EF. The amount of effort needed to alleviate those problems (see answer below) is so big though that I personally don't bother and accept the slight toll EF takes on my entities. It is anyway infinitely better now with Code First + Fluent mapping than it was in the early versions.

Comment: *"I also tried reconstructing and replaying the method calls which would cause the entity to be in an equivalent state"* - this looks a lot like Event Sourcing, another elegant way of (not having to) solve the O/R mismatch problem. Maybe you should look into that.

Comment: How would I overcome obstacle 3 with EF, where the database is less normalized than the model? I like the idea of event sourcing but I am not ready to revamp the database.

Comment: Can you please detail "the database is less normalized than the model" (normalization isn't a very relevant concept in the OO world) and give a concrete example of how this hampers you ?

Comment: For example, the database has a Formulas table with a State field (proposed, approved, transmitted). The domain model has FormulaEntry with two fields, State and Formula. FormulaEntry has timeline-state-specific methods on it which are not a concern of Formula. Formula has its own set of complicated behaviors and supports unsaved what-if scenarios. To map from the database, I need to unflatten each row from the Formulas table into a FormulaEntry. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. Are you saying that `FormulaEntry` is at higher aggregation level than `Formula` ? Is this for read-only reporting purposes or can you actually modify a `Formula` through its `FormulaEntry` and if so how (functionally speaking) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81538/discussion-between-guillaume31-and-jnm2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to use the Memento pattern which is solid but boring and has a high maintenance cost. It's great that you've realized that working directly with EF entities (regardless how POCO they are) is an issue, however there is a simple solution.

Treat your EF POCOs strictly as DTOs to read/write from db. If you're using the [Repository pattern](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/02/The-Repository-Pattern-For-Dummies.aspx) correctly then you can map (manually or with automapper) your Aggregate Roots to EF POCOs **inside** the repository.

The rest of the app wouldn't know anything about EF, only your repo will act as a 'converter' from domain objects to one or more EF POCOs and back. In order to get data into a Domain object you can define the 'read-only' properties like

```
 List<string> _data=new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Data
{
      get{ return _data;}
      private set{
          _data=value.ToList();
         }
 }
```

This will allow a tool like automapper to populate the object state. Note that the object is still encapsulated, but the private setters also act as data  'importers'.

Personally I'm using this approach but without EF, as a prefer to json the object and store it as such. Ofc, the table has the required columns for queries but there's the `Data` column which holds the objects state that can be easily restored. As long as your aggregates are properly designed, it works beautifully.

Comment: So your solution is AutoMapper to access internal state, rather than a Materialize method that has legal C# access to internal state?

Comment: "Legal" really? Look, you can use a factory method all day long but you're going to write boring code for a long time. The end result is the same, you have to choose who's going to do the work: you or a tool.

Comment: Fair point. But would I not be writing a similar amount of boring mapping code if I used AutoMapper? Maybe I misunderstand AutoMapper.

Comment: The guy who wrote AutoMapper [wouldn't use it in this scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28585993/521757). I would have to do lots of mapping configuration (see reasons 3 and 4 why I'm not using EF). His comments on [this blog post](http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper) are also informative.

Comment: Automapper was just a suggestion. The point is to use a tool, instead of doing things manually. Since personally I json the objects, I'm using json.net for this purpose.