# Automapper map to tuple which first element is list second one is simple property

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I need to map this results, but getting error:
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 'Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.'

```
public class ResponseModel
    {
        public int TotalPageCount { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ExternalAPIResponseModel> ExternalAPIResponse { get; set; } = new List<ExternalAPIResponseModel>();
    }


 public class ExternalAPIResponseModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string JobFunction { get; set; }
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }


 public class Contact
    {
        public int Ocid { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        // etc.
    }

 
//I know the mistake is here
CreateMap<(IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts, int pagesCount), ResponseModel>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.ExternalAPIResponse.Select( x=>new {
                       x.Address,
                       x.CompanyName,
                       x.FirstName,
                       x.LastName,
                       x.JobFunction,
                       x.JobLevel,
                       x.Email,
                       x.Phone,
                       x.State
                   }),
                   
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Contacts.Select(c=> new { 
                    c.ContactAddress1,
                    c.HqcompanyName,
                    c.FirstName,
                    c.LastName,
                    c.IdjobFunctionNavigation.JobFunction1,
                    c.IdjobLevelNavigation.JobLevel1,
                    c.Email,
                    c.ContactPhone,
                    c.ContactState })))
                         
               .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalPageCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.pagesCount));
   
    //I call it from conntroller like this 
    var mappedResult = _mapper.Map<ResponseModel>(result);
```

How can I map (IEnumerable Contacts, int pagesCount) to the ResponseModel in order to not get error ?

Comment: Are you sure you want `IEnumerable<ResponseModel>`? I feel u just need `ResponseModel` because it has `IEnumerable<ExternalAPIResponseModel>` which will be  mapped from `IEnumerable<Contact>`

Comment: Yes you right, there is mistake I will fix, I need just ResponseModel

Comment: What the Type of `result`?  Is it a `Tuple` or  `IEnumerable<Contacts>` or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Tuple**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple) `Tuple<IEnumerable<Contact>, int>` and then Map it to `ResponseModel`

**Mapper**

```cs
   CreateMap<Contact, ExternalAPIResponseModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.FirstName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.LastName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.HqcompanyName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ContactAddress1))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.JobFunction, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IdjobFunctionNavigation.JobFunction1))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.JobLevel, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IdjobLevelNavigation.JobLevel1))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Email))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ContactPhone))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ContactState));

    CreateMap<Tuple<IEnumerable<Contact>, int>, ResponseModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ExternalAPIResponse, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Item1))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalPageCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Item2));
```

**In Controller**

```cs
int pagesCount = 10;
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = GetListOfContacts(pagesCount);
Tuple<IEnumerable<Contact>, int> result = Tuple.Create(contacts, pagesCount);
var mappedResult = _mapper.Map<ResponseModel>(result);
```

Comment: This is _manual_ mapping, you don't need AM for that!

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu  "I use AutoMapper when I want to get rid of boring left-hand-side right-hand-side code. If the logic isn't completely obvious for copying data, I revert back to manual mapping."  - Words from your very own Jimmy Bogard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574187/when-should-i-be-using-automapper-and-when-not...

Comment: Yes, but this is not simple manual mapping, it's obfuscated through improper use of AM, the worst of both worlds :)

Comment: In certain cases it so happens that we have to use Automapper like this to keep consistency with the design... If there are 99 other cases we can leverage the AutoMapper functionality and one such scenario where we cannot it's okay..

Comment: A type converter works best in such cases.